# Error 400 - Bad request with Flask request.get_data() from PHP request

Tags: php, python, curl, post, flask

I'm doing an internal API across my servers. 
I want to transfer some **JSON strings** from PHP to Python.

On Python, I have this code:

```
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
...

@app.route('/database/<string:token>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sync(token):
    if token not in VALID_TOKENS:
        ...

    json = request.get_json(force=True)
    ...

...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, port=6000)
```

On PHP-side, I have:

```
$payload = $datafromdatabase; 
$payload = json_encode($payload); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload))                                                                       
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

But Flask returns me, at every request:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2017 20:08:00] "POST /database/token HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

P.S: On Python, `request.data` and `request.args` are both `None`.

P.P.S.: Using `requests.post(url, json=data)` in Python works.

Comment: run flask in debug mode: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=6000)`. What happens?

Comment: Where is `$data_string` defined? your are calculating the content-length from that unknown variable, not from `$payload`

Comment: @ChristianEichelmann I edited, but the problem it isn't on it.